# Foreach from knockout not working with jssor slider

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, slider, jssor

I'm using jssor Carousel Slider with foundation css framework. I want generate all data dynamically with knockout (there is additional layer on every slide where I placed pricing table).

[Here](http://niesamowite.eu.pn/cdn/static.html) it's what i want to get. It's working because I do it static - just copy and paste every slide.

When I'm using knockouts foreach loop I got [this](http://niesamowite.eu.pn/cdn/dynamic.html).

My viewmodel:

```
 function DogsListViewModel() {
 
     var self = this;
 
     self.dogsList = ko.observableArray([
         { "Name": "NameDog1", "Breed": "Dog1Breed", "Desc": "Dog1Description", "Price": "00.00" },
         { "Name": "NameDog2", "Breed": "Dog2Breed", "Desc": "Dog2Description", "Price": "01.00" },
         { "Name": "NameDog3", "Breed": "Dog3Breed", "Desc": "Dog3Description", "Price": "02.00" },
         { "Name": "NameDog4", "Breed": "Dog4Breed", "Desc": "Dog4Description", "Price": "03.00" }
     ]); 
}
 
 $(document).ready(function () {
     ko.applyBindings(new DogsListViewModel()); });
```

And html source:

```
<!-- START SLIDER -->    
    <!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
    <div id="slider1_container" class="cd">

        <!-- Loading Screen -->
        <div u="loading" class="load">
            <div class="loadbg">
            </div>
            <div class="loadico">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <ul>
        <div u="slides" class="slidercontainer img-list">           
         <!-- ko foreach: dogsList --> 
          <div>
            <x>
            <img u="image" src="http://curezone.com/upload/Members/new03/siberian_husky_dog.jpg" />
                <span class="text-content">
                    <span>
                        <div class="fix-table">
                            <ul class="pricing-table">
                             <li class="title" data-bind="text: Name"></li>
                             <li class="bullet-item" data-bind="text: Breed"></li>
                             <li class="description" data-bind="text: Desc"></li>
                             <li class="price" data-bind="text: Price"></li>      
                             <li class="fix-cta-button">
                              <a href="#" class="button">More</a>&nbsp;
                              <a href="#" class="button alert">Buy</a>
                             </li>
                           </ul>
                       </div>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </x>
          </div>
      <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
        </ul>    
    </div>
    <!-- Jssor Slider End -->
   <!-- END SLIDER -->
```

I think it should just repeat four times all `<div>` which contains `<x>`, but I got just black square.
How can I fix it? Where is a bug? I can't find any example with jssor and knockout.

EDIT:

Thanks for @jevgenig I know that all images are binded successfully but not in another slide - all images stacked one on top of other.

Comment: When I open your link, all images are successfully binded there, just check it from DOM, there are all 4 of them, they are just stacked one on top of other

Comment: @jevgenig: yes, you're right but I still don't know how to move images - it's a slider so after 0.5 second all images should move to left and again and again. And additional question: why last image (from top) don't show?

Comment: I cannot access your link. But make sure the size of 'slides' container is big enough to display a certain number of slides (include the last image).

Comment: @jssor: Which link not working? I can change hosting but everything works for me. Size of slider container is ok.

Comment: @jssor: sorry for this, I'm using free hosting and I don't know about any restricts. Links has been changed, i hope these will be working.

Comment: @1_bug: the new link works.

Comment: I copied all codes from http://niesamowite.eu.pn/cdn/dynamic.html. It works on my local machine. But I don't know why it doesn't work at your site.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the data-bind for the foreach at the level you want to repeat, this repeats at the body level of the table, creating a row for each iteration binding the data accordingly

```
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th></th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: members">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Email"></td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-bind="visible: RegisterEmailSent">Send</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```